# Will AndroidX Refactoring Support work instead of android.support.v4 and android.support.v7?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I read the article about AndroidX Refactoring Support at https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/android-studio-32.html.

To my understanding AndroidX will work instead of android.support.v4 and android.support.v7, right?

So in my new project, I don't need to import android.support.v4 and android.support.v7 again, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to android.com's page [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), it has a list of which AndroidX package replaces each legacy package. It also has a list of which namespace a particular class has been moved to. To convert to using the AndroidX version, you have to replace the appropriate 'artifact' in your gradle dependencies, *and* you have to change your import statement to whatever namespace the class is in now.

For example, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` is now called `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`. So you'll need to change your import statement, *and* you'll need to add the relevant AndroidX library to dependencies in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

So yes, you don't have to reference android.support.v4, you have to reference the appropriate new library.